# How would the Gates of Ivory and Horn from the Odyssey be said in ancient Greek?

Tags: greek

How would one say the name of each individual gate from the Gates of Ivory and Horn? According to the Odyssey, they are located in the underworld near the Asphodel fields. I have found that (ἐλέφας) is ivory, and (κέρας) is horn. Pylai means gates(plural) as far as I can tell. So, what would each individual gate be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the Greek is set on the genitive singular for "ivory" and genitive plural for "horn". Moreover, the singular of "gate" in Greek is πύλη.

So you get **πύλη ἐλέφαντος** and **πύλη κεράων**. These are missing the articles, as they would in epic poetry, but in later prose, you would see a definite article for each noun.